# Applying a git patch to a different non-local repository

Tags: git, github

I have two repositories.

One that I've been working on for month, with about 20 commits and pushes,
And a new one I locally made.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I need to push each commit to the new repository, and not just merge the two codes. I cannot add remote and then do cherry-pick, this is not an option for me.

What I'm thinking is to apply patches from one repo to another. Is this possible?

**Things I tried so far:**
git add -p patch file that is generated for the commit

That did not work.
Any ideas on how to apply patch to a different repository?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably want [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am).

Comment: Although I don't understand why you can't add a remote and cherry pick. If you push the new repository to somewhere remote it won't automatically pick up state from the original repository. And you say that the new repository is local, but the problem is applying patches to a different non-local repository?